# Should I use CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE while using LBP CascadeClassifier?

Tags: opencv, local-features, classification, c++

I trained a cascade-LBP to detect Lollipops with 1000 images, now I'm trying to "adapt" the openCV HAAR-Cascade example to use my LBP trained .xml but I'm not sure about the "HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE" flag, I read that optimizes the downscale to increase the HAAR features is it right to use it with LBP?

`//-- Detect Lollipops
  lollipops_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, lollipops, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );`

An example of imput image:
[image: Lollipops]

For more info:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenCV documentation suggests using CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE when performing a detectMultiScale with LBP features.

```
lollipops_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, lollipops,1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
```

Even though, it works perfectly with  `CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE` flag instead of `CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE`.

Answer (score -1):

According to EMGU, which is an .NET wrapper for OpenCV, and sometimes has way better documentation than OpenCV,

> DO_CANNY_PRUNING
>   If it is set, the function uses Canny edge detector
>   to reject some image regions that contain too few or too much edges
>   and thus can not contain the searched object. The particular threshold
>   values are tuned for face detection and in this case the pruning
>   speeds up the processing
>
> SCALE_IMAGE
>   For each scale factor used the function will downscale
>   the image rather than "zoom" the feature coordinates in the classifier
>   cascade. Currently, the option can only be used alone, i.e. the flag
>   can not be set together with the others
>
> FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
>   If it is set, the function finds the largest
>   object (if any) in the image. That is, the output sequence will
>   contain one (or zero) element(s)
>
> DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
>   It should be used only when
>   CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT is set and min_neighbors > 0. If the flag
>   is set, the function does not look for candidates of a smaller size as
>   soon as it has found the object (with enough neighbor candidates) at
>   the current scale. Typically, when min_neighbors is fixed, the mode
>   yields less accurate (a bit larger) object rectangle than the regular
>   single-object mode (flags=CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT), but it is much
>   faster, up to an order of magnitude. A greater value of min_neighbors may be specified to improve the accuracy.

[Source](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/e2278977-87ea-8fa9-b78e-0e52cfe6406a.htm)